# Pipe babel to nodeunit via gulp without writing transpiled files to disk

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, nodeunit

I'm trying to run nodeunit tests with support of ES6 features. To make feature support wider I use [Babeljs transpiler](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#gulp).

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.
    src('src/**/*.js').
    pipe(babel()).
    pipe(gulp.dest("/dev/null")). // I'd like to get rid of it
    pipe(nodeunit()).
    on('error', function() {
        this.emit('end');
    });
});
```

The issue is that I don't wan't to write transpiled files to disk, I just want to pass them to nodeunit task. If I remove `pipe(gulp.dest("/dev/null"))` it seems that `pipe(babel())` does nothing or just outputs somewhere in the void. When `gulp.dest` is in place everything works fine except that it writes files I don't need. So, is it possible to avoid transpiled files writing? And how?

P. S. I know the following ways, but they don't suit me:

1. I can use io.js to get wider ES6 support
2. I can just delete files after tests are run

Comment: Most test framework (in my experience) need to have the files written out somewhere so they can be executed. Karma definitely does, although Mocha doesn't explicitly require it.

Comment: Seems like it would be much easier to use `nodeunit` with `babel/register` to compile at runtime instead.

Comment: Point of @ssube makes sense. Maybe it is not a gulp problem, but nodeunit requirement.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I don't like `babel/register` pollutes global scope, so I'd rather stay with writing files I don't need. But anyway thanks for the idea.

Comment: @ViktorMolokostov Could you elaborate? Your exist test example would also rely on global polyfils unless you're switching on `runtime` but your sample code doesn't mention that so I wasn't sure.